# ## preprocessor operator and value of a variable

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have searched and seems it is not possible to do this in C using ## preprocessor operator.

I want to use a variable value and make a function name like MY_FUNC_3

I know that how to use '#define VALUE 3' and do this, but how I can do same with a variable.

```
#define PASTE(x,y) x ## y
#define function (func_name, value) PASTE(x,y)

int a= 3;

for (int a = 2; a < 10; a++)
{
    printf("%s\n", function(MY_FUNC, a))
}
```

Comment: All the pre processor Macros will be replaced during compilation. What you are trying to achieve is to be done during run time. Why cant you use `sprintf()` instead?

Comment: `#define function (func_name, value) PASTE(x,y)` should probably read `#define function (func_name, value) PASTE(func_name, value)`, but then why even bother creating an alias?

Comment: Can you write out manually what you are trying to achieve? I don't think we expect the same thing from looking at the code.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you expect to get from this, but the fundamental problem is that the preprocessor runs at the start of the compilation and has no clue about variables, loops, and the like.  It does simple text substitution.  You simply can't do whatever you were trying to do the way you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using the pre-processor, as it is invoke before compilation, so it does not know anything about possible run-time behaviour.

You could solve this using an array of functions, or more precise using an array of functions pointers, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * function1(void)
{
  return "Result 1";
}

const char * function2(void)
{
  return "Result 2";
}

const char * function3(void)
{
  return "Result 3";
}

const char * (*functions[])(void) = {
  function1,
  function2,
  function3,
  NULL
};

int main(void)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  while (NULL != functions[i])
  {
    printf("function[%zu]: '%s'\n", i, functions[i]());
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
function[0]: 'Result 1'
function[1]: 'Result 2'
function[2]: 'Result 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the preprocessor value holding a char, but you can do it like:

```
#define PASTE_(x, y) x ##y
#define PASTE(x, y) PASTE_(x, y)

#define value 3
void PASTE(FuncName, value)()
{...}
```